How to select the direct children from the root element with cheerio
Suppose you have the following setup (the numbers are there just for reference and should be ignored):
const html = `
<div 1>
  <div>...</div>
  <div 2>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  ...
</div>`;
$ = cheerio.load(html, null, false);

The three dots can also contain nested divs and other html!
How would I select the  div 1? I tried
  $(':scope')     -> null
  $('>div')       -> null

For some reason I cannot select the first/root div.
But even if that makes sense, how would you select its direct children (div 2). I tried
 $(':scope>div')              -> null
 $().children().eq(1)         -> null
 $(':scope').children().eq(1) -> null

I get the impression :scope does not do what I think it does. Any suggestions?

$('div[1]') ? Please note that 1 is an illegal attribute name.

True, but I've added it here just for my question, so I cannot do div[1]

once you loaded that html string into the $ variable .. did you try to just use $('div').first() ? it should return the first div found .. but such strategy applies only to the scenario you shared. By the way I think cheerio doesn't support :scope

more in general I think this should work to get the root element of the fragment loaded $.root().children().first() ... in this case the document contains only one element among its children (the root element) .. but in general the html given could have many siblings

This seems overly contrived. Is this your actual HTML structure? It's very strange to only have one totally unmarked root div (no class or id) with 3 totally unmarked inner divs, and nothing else to work off of. I'd provide a more realistic, actual problem, because something is likely lost in the simplification here. If this is your actual markup, please explain where it came from and what you're trying to do with it. Strong XY problem vibes.

I'm parsing a website which uses random generated class names (like x.com), so I can only rely on html structure. But with all the answers and suggestions given my problems are solved :) Thnx for the help!

I'm not sure why you want to do this and the structure is unusual (there is usually some identifying characteristic--attributes, text content or some unordered identifier you can use), but the following should work to select the outer div:
$("div:first-of-type"); // if you know it's a div
$("*:first-of-type"); // if you have no idea what the root is

Then, to select the second child:
import cheerio from "cheerio"; // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `
<div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
</div>`;
const $ = cheerio.load(html, null, false);
console.log($(":first-of-type > :nth-child(2)").text()); // => b
console.log($(":first-child > :nth-child(2)").text()); // => b
console.log($(":first-child > :nth-of-type(2)").text()); // => b

Generally speaking, avoid "nth" selectors except as a last resort. Structures based on ordering are more liable to change than classes and ids are. Ordering is unreliable for testing, styling and scraping.
